# Why "object not interpretable as a factor" error coming in correct code?

Tags: r

I was running a code in R and got stuck at a point where it showing me an error "object not interpretable as a factor" again and again .I searched for it and at stack overflow I found a similar problem asked by someone else ,though in his case it was a typo where he was using a capital "C" instead of small "c" .but in my case I was using correct still I got this error .why ??

Here is my code in which I got the error :

```
roulette_vector <- c("losses" = 24, "losses" = 50, "winnings" = 100, "losses" = 350, "winnings" = 10)
```

Comment: I do not get the error

Comment: I don't get the error either. Are you sure that running this exact line of code, in isolation, produced the error?

Comment: sekhr, do not be put off by one downvote. a single downvote is the opinion of a single user, not the whole of Stack Overflow. please do not add meta-discussion into your question; I have edited this out.

Answer (score 1):

I do not get the error. However, you can try to create the vector and then assign the names and check if you still get the error.

```
roulette_vector <- c(24, 50, 100, 350, 10)
names(roulette_vector)  <- c("losses", "losses", "winnings", "losses", "winnings")
```